# UISegmentedControl with badge number

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, uisegmentedcontrol, badge

Just like the tabbar, I want to show badge on `UISegmentedControl`. As I cant see any predefined methods for `UISegmentedControl` just like available for `UITabBar`.

[image]

I thought about adding the badge as an image just on top of it, but maybe there is some better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge) is a little third party library I've used to draw badges on various things. It's pretty nice. For example, changing the color of the badge to match my design was trivial.

Once you bring this class into your project and include it into your view controller, you go:

```
CustomBadge *customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"Badge 1"];
```

...and then add customBadge1 as a subview of whatever thing you're badging.

Comment: I've created a UISegmentedControl subclass that uses this library and makes badging even easier - see my answer below.

Comment: cannot do with native?!~

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem today, so I've put together a UISegmentedControl subclass which allows you to easily set badge numbers on each of the segments.

Using it's as easy as:

```
[segmentedControl setBadgeNumber:1 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Screenshot, documentation and source code are at https://github.com/dave-thompson/MESegmentedControl .

Answer (score 0):

There is no badge property or method - unlike the tab bar. If you want to do this you will just have to put a custom image over it. You could subclass the segmented control and create a function that does this for you.

Comment: Yeah i too think this is possible using custom image only. Thanks for reply