# Is there a built-in class for creating notification badges?

Tags: ios4, notifications, badge

I've noticed that some apps (like the Facebook and LinkedIn iPhone apps) have notification badges inside the app (I'm not talking about the ones in the tab bar, I know how to create those). How are they achieving this? Are they using images or this there a built-in class for creating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have a look at this [CustomBadge Library](http://www.spaulus.com/2010/09/create-a-custom-iphone-ipad-badge/?lang=en) from a [stack overflow member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077140/uisegmentedcontrol-with-badge)